# How to use a mixins function inside another mixins function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

How do I combine two functions in vue mixins??

```
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
      functionOne: () => {
        console.log(1)
      }
      functionTwo: () => {
        this.functionOne()
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.functionTwo()
    }
})
```

//expected: console
1

//actual: console
Cannot read property 'functionOne' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

if you use ES6 arrow functions with Vue methods, it changes the context of `this`. If you phrase it like:

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    functionOne () {
      console.log(1)
    },
    functionTwo: function () {
      this.functionOne()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.functionTwo()
  }
})
```

it works perfectly.

(the `functionOne ()` and `functionTwo: function ()` syntax are both valid, which is why they both appear in the example.)